# Open a serial port with arduino using c++ with Xcode on mac

Tags: c++, xcode, serialization, serial-port, arduino

I've written a simple program in c++ which sends an angle value to an Arduino through a serial port; the Arduino than uses the value to control a servo motor.

This is c++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int angle;
    fstream arduino;
    
    cout<<"check-1";

    arduino.open("/dev/tty.usbmodem3a21");

    cout<<"check-2";
    
    if(arduino)
    {
        do
        {
            cout<<"\n\ninsert a number between 0 and 179";
        
            cin>>angle;
            arduino<<angle;
            
        }while(angle <= 179);
        
        arduino.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\n\nERROR!!\n\n";
    }
    
    
}
```

and this is arduino's:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo;
const int pinServo = 2;
unsigned int angle;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    servo.attach(pinServo);
    
    servo.write(0);
    
}

void loop()
{
    if(Serial.available()>0)
    {  
       angle = Serial.read();
       
       if(angle <= 179)
       {
         servo.write(angle);
       }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it stops at `arduino.open(...)`. Despite I checked that the selected port in the Arduino app in *tools > serial* port is correct, it doesn't even print out "check-1".

To add more useful information, I tested opening the port with the `iOS::binary` parameter so the opening command becomes `arduino.open("/dev/tty.usbmodem3a21",iOS::binary)`; as a result, this prints out "check-1", "check-2" and "ERROR!!".  I get the same results if I type in a wrong serial port name.

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Comment: Why are you sure that it stops at the `open` if it doesn't even print the first check?

Comment: This is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677639/two-way-c-communication-over-serial-connection - You need to set the baud rate and turn off hardware flow control.

Answer (score 1):

The arduino shows up as a serial device. You should look at using the `open()` and `close()` function. I've done this on Linux but I'm pretty sure this works similarly on Mac. This is an example snippet of code. The first snippet opens and sets up the file descriptor.

```
int fd;                             // File descriptor
// Open port
fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if (fd == -1){
    printf("Device cannot be opened.\n");
    exit(-1);                       // If the device is not open, return -1
}
struct termios options;

fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);                    // Open the device in nonblocking mode

// Set parameters
tcgetattr(fd, &options);                        // Get the current options of the port
bzero(&options, sizeof(options));               // Clear all the options
speed_t         Speed;
switch (baudRate)                               // Set the speed (baudRate)
{
    case 110  :     Speed=B110; break;
    case 300  :     Speed=B300; break;
    case 600  :     Speed=B600; break;
    case 1200 :     Speed=B1200; break;
    case 2400 :     Speed=B2400; break;
    case 4800 :     Speed=B4800; break;
    case 9600 :     Speed=B9600; break;
    case 19200 :    Speed=B19200; break;
    case 38400 :    Speed=B38400; break;
    case 57600 :    Speed=B57600; break;
    case 115200 :   Speed=B115200; break;
    default : exit(-4);
}
cfsetispeed(&options, Speed);                   // Set the baud rate at 115200 bauds
cfsetospeed(&options, Speed);
options.c_cflag |= ( CLOCAL | CREAD |  CS8);    // Configure the device : 8 bits, no parity, no control
options.c_iflag |= ( IGNPAR | IGNBRK );
options.c_cc[VTIME]=0;                          // Timer unused
options.c_cc[VMIN]=0;                           // At least on character before satisfy reading
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);               // Activate the settings
```

This just closes it:

```
close(fd);
```

To read from the actual file descriptor:

```
ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &t1);                           
if(t1 > 0) {
    // If the number of bytes read is equal to the number of bytes retrieved
    if(read(fd,pByte, t1) == t1) {  
        for(int i =0; i < t1; i++) {
            if(pByte[i] != '\r'){ // Just makes sure you're not scanning new lines
                // TODO: Do what you want with this character
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do before sending the commands with your program in c++ is that the serialport is correctly configured, you simply have the serial port closed loop, everything you send should receive, If you do not receive anything you have a serial port configuration problem